# Disable ringtone fade-in

Tags: settings, ringtone

My Moto Z2 Play includes a "feature" where call rings and alarm sounds start out nearly silent and increase to full volume over about five seconds. I have been unable to find any setting to change this behavior. Media audio (games, apps, etc.) is not affected.

In the stock clock app settings, I have "Gradually increase volume" set to "Never". I'm seems that there is an OS or hardware level setting or feature that is overriding the clock app setting.

I have found an app that purportedly solves this problem, but it requires an unsettling number of permissions to function. Is there no native way to disable this "feature"?

(I understand that this behavior provides utility for some people. For me, it merely ruins my ringtones and makes me more likely to miss calls.)

Comment: Did you try `adb shell`? Execute `settings list system` and see if something like `increasing_ring` exists.

Comment: For alarm clock there should be checkbox called "increasing volume" or something like that.

Comment: In the clock settings, I have "Gradually increase volume" set to "Never". I'm seems that there is an OS or hardware level setting it feature that is overriding the clock app.